# Delete Realm object automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, realm

I am experimenting with a sample realm code and I added an option to automatically delete a specific object based on a certain value. But what I need to do is reload the tableview but when I add [baseTableView reloadData]; the app crashes with the exception "Object has been deleted or invalidated". Does anyone know how can I fix this so the tableview updates and removes the row that was automatically deleted. My delete code is:

```
-(IBAction)delline:(id)sender
{




NSInteger count = [QueueArray count];
for (NSInteger index = (count - 1); index >= 0; index--) {
    person = QueueArray[index];
    if ([person.emailaddress1 isEqualToString:@"test"]) {

          NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
            [dbManager deleteRealmObject:[QueueArray objectAtIndex:index]];
            NSLog(@"DELETE PATH: %ld", (long)index);
            // set to whatever you want to be selected first
            [baseTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

            UITableViewCell *cell = [baseTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        [baseTableView reloadData];

    }

}


}
```

Comment: You have to update your DataSource before calling `reloadData`. The Realm object is deleted in Realm but still in your DataSource. So, it tries to retrieve the object from Realm when you call `reloadData` without finding it.

Comment: @cesarmarch That is a great comment. The only thing is that if the OP is using a Results object as their dataSource, removing it from realm also removes it from the results. That does not appear the case but wanted to add that for clarity.